# apply methods of most objects jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

e.g.

```
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
var $magicLine2 = $("#magic-line2");
```

how do I apply the methods to two objects?
I now use:

```
$magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width()
$magicLine2.width($(".current_page_item").width()
```

if i use this method the programm not work:

```
$magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width()
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you exactly want to do? What is the problem?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket after each `.width()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#magic-line, #magic-line2").width($(".current_page_item").width());
```

your question is a bit vague, i think you mean to use one call for both?

Comment: almost, I wanted to do something like that: $("#magic-line, #magic-line2").width($(".current_page_item").width());
but in this way: $($magic-line, $magic-line2).width($(".current_page_item").width()); First i have create 'var $magicline = $('magic-line') and 'var $magicline2 = $('magic-line2'). Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to write?

```
var magicLine = $("#magic-line");
var magicLine2 = $("#magic-line2");

$magicLine.width($(magicLine).width());
$magicLine2.width($(magicLine2).width());
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width());
$magicLine2.width($(".current_page_item").width());
```

you may choose this:

```
$.each([$magicLine, $magicLine2],function(i, value){value.width($(".current_page_item").width())});
```

Comment: i want make the same but in an unique line so that: $magicline,$magicline2.width(....). I did before $('#magicline,#magicline2')

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
var magicLine = $("#magic-line");

magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width());
```